# How to allow -z multidefs with g++47

Tags: c++, linker, g++, flags, linker-flags

How can I tell the linker of `g++` to allow multiple definitions of symbols (choose the first appearance)?

> -z multidefs  Allows multiple symbol definitions. By default, multiple symbol definitions occurring between relocatable objects (.o files)
>   will result in a fatal error condition. This option suppresses the
>   error condition and allows the first symbol definition to be taken.
>   This option is valid only when the -b svr4 option is specified.

The `-zmuldefs` option is not recognized by `g++`, nor `-z OPTION`. What's the correct parameter? Is it possible?

Comment: you should nail the issue in the code first, why do you have multiple definitions?

Comment: @billz Both ITK and opencv define encode and decode functions of jasper. This does not cause any trouble on Linux nor Windows, only Mac (gcc47 from MacPorts). The code is not the problem. I've solved it by compiling opencv without Jasper, but I still want to be able to overcome this issue by allowing multiple definitions which are the same.

Comment: I believe I was using the -Xlinker option wrong, I have to use it for every parameter, I'll get back to it in an hour.

Comment: Do you have multiple definitions in one compilation unit, or in few? I was unable to compile with "-z muldefs" when I put multiple definitions in one file, but when I put them in two, compiled with g++ -c, and then linked with g++ -z muldefs, I only got warning "/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `add(int, int)' changed from 18 in test.o to 20 in test2.o"

Comment: @Alex1985 In few. However, the option is not recognized at all, so I believe I'm inputing it wrong.

Comment: Mmh, I've realized that `ld -z` does also spit out ùnrecognized option`, which made me discover that Mac does not use gnu ld.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as the "linker of g++", it uses your system's own linker.

To pass options through from GCC to the linker you need to use GCC's `-Wl,` or `-Xlinker` options:

> `-Xlinker option`
>     Pass `option` as an option to the linker.  You can use this to supply system-specific linker options which GCC does not know how to recognize.
>     If you want to pass an option that takes a separate argument, you must use `-Xlinker` twice, once for the option and once for the argument.  For example,
>     to pass `-assert definitions`, you must write `-Xlinker -assert -Xlinker definitions`.  It does not work to write `-Xlinker "-assert definitions"`, because
>              this passes the entire string as a single argument, which is not what the linker expects.
>              When using the GNU linker, it is usually more convenient to pass arguments to linker options using the `option=value` syntax than as separate arguments.
>              For example, you can specify `-Xlinker -Map=output.map` rather than `-Xlinker -Map -Xlinker output.map`.  Other linkers may not support this syntax for
>              command-line options.
>
> `-Wl,option`
>      Pass `option` as an option to the linker.  If `option` contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.  You can use this syntax to pass
>      an argument to the option.  For example, `-Wl,-Map,output.map` passes `-Map output.map` to the linker.  When using the GNU linker, you can also get the
>      same effect with `-Wl,-Map=output.map`.

So you would want to use

```
-Xlinker -z -Xlinker multidefs
```

or

```
-Wl,-z,multidefs
```

but the docs you quoted say you must also use `-b svr4` to use that option, e.g.

```
-Wl,-b,svr4,-z,multidefs
```

**Edit:** From your comments I see you're on Mac OS X, which uses the darwin linker, and its [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html) shows the corresponding option is obsolete:

> `-m`  Don't treat multiple definitions as an error. This is no longer supported. This option is obsolete.

Comment: THank you @Jonathan It looks like the XCode system's `ld` is not the GNU linker, since it does not recognize those options. In fact `-b` is deprecated. So, how can I tell the linker to ignore multiple definitions?

Comment: Oh, and somebody knows what linker is Mac's XCode using?

Comment: It uses the darwin linker, see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html, which says "-m          Don't treat multiple definitions as an error.  This is no longer supported. This option is
                 obsolete."

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible to do what I intended, since apparently gnu ld is not supported either.

Comment: If you post the previous comment as an answer and rephrase it a little bit I'll mark it as an answer, although the question has become ambiguous indeed.

Answer (score 5):

GCC uses `ld` as linker in linux, which is part of `binutils` created by GNU.

It seems the newer version of `ld` do not support `-z muldefs` option. You can try to use `--allow-multiple-definition` as an alternative.

Comment: As Jonathan Wakely said, there is no "GCC Linker", it uses `ld` of `GNU binutils` as the linker. The newest `GNU binutil` is version 2.28, which seems do not support `-z muldef` option. You can use `--allow-multiple-definitions` as a replacement.

Comment: it is actually --allow-multiple-definition, without an 's'

Comment: @philipp Corrected.