# What is the clang++ or LLVM linker equivalent of g++ -z multidefs?

Tags: c++, linker, llvm, clang++

What is the clang++ or LLVM linker equivalent of `g++ -z multidefs`?

That is, how to allow multiple definitions or allow duplicate symbols (as clang++ calls them) in the linker.

In case of g++, it is by passing `-z multidefs` as a Flag.

How to achieve the same with clang++?

Comment: Are you talking about Linux or some other OS? It matters.

Comment: @MikeKinghan OS X

Comment: `-z <arg>` is just passed on to the linker, for both compilers AFAIK. What linker are you using?

Comment: @mindriot ```ld```

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443976/how-to-allow-z-multidefs-with-g47), the apple linker does not support this anymore.